# Invalid or corrupt JAR File built by Maven shade plugin

Tags: java, maven, jfreechart, maven-shade-plugin

After adding the Maven jFree dependency to my existing application, I'm not able to execute the created jar.

The only error message I get is the following:

```
java -jar target/com.company.product-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile target/com. company.product-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The complete `pom.xml` looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>com.mycompany.test</artifactId>
<name>${project.artifactId}</name>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.springframework.data-version>1.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.data-version>
    <org.springframework.ws-version>2.0.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.ws-version>
    <org.springframework.ws.oxm-version>1.5.10</org.springframework.ws.oxm-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.12</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
    <selenium-java-version>2.25.0</selenium-java-version>
    <browser-mob-version>2.0-beta-6</browser-mob-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Hint A: If we delete this dependency it works -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.14</version>
                    <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.schlichtherle.io</groupId>
        <artifactId>truezip</artifactId>
        <version>6.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Caching with ehcache -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.java-persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpa-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-cr-1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1-Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Database Connectors (HSQL should be removed later) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Data JPA dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.data-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.ws.oxm-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.ws-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.ws-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Common Utils -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>       

    <!-- Selenium -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium-java-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium-java-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium-java-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- CSV Lib for Keyword Checker -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Google Places API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.3-beta</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client-appengine</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.3-beta</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Google Geocode -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.geocoder-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>geocoder-java</artifactId>
        <version>0.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jgrapht</groupId>
        <artifactId>jgrapht</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jgraph</groupId>
        <artifactId>jgraph</artifactId>
        <version>5.13.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Http Client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Amazon web services client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Docx4j - reading excel files  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Browser Mob Proxy -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>biz.neustar</groupId>
        <artifactId>browsermob-proxy</artifactId>
        <version>${browser-mob-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hint B: If we copy this Apache POI dependencies to the top, it works -->
    <!-- Apache POI - for reading xlsx files -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>

                            <!-- must be SURE to do this with both spring.handlers and spring.schemas. 
                                otherwise you won't be able to use them in the spring config files. -->
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>

                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>

                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.mycompany.test.Start</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>

                        <filters>
                          <filter>
                            <artifact>bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                              <exclude>META-INF/BCKEY.DSA</exclude>
                              <exclude>META-INF/BCKEY.SF</exclude>
                              <exclude>META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                          </filter>
                        </filters>                          

                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

I don't get any other debug information if I execute the jar.

Is there any option to validate the jarfile? Or having something like `java -verbose`...?

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. create a new folder
2. Copy the Pom.xml from above into the folder.
3. Save the small `public static void main(...). into src/main/java/com/mycompany/test/Start.java
4. execute `mvn clean package`
5. execute `java -jar target/com.mycompany.test-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

**Attachment 1:**

```
package com.mycompany.test;


public class Start
{
    public static void main(final String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("If you are able to get this printed with java -jar you made it. Thanks a lot! :)");
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:**

I started to delete some dependencies to identify the problem. But I haven't got a clear understanding what goes wrong.

Now I figured out (See hint B in the pom.xml) that moving the Apache POI dependencies to the top will solve the problem. But still I don't know how to why and what is the problem.

Comment: Interesting the error includes target/comcompany.product instead of target/com.company.product  or is that just a typo entering the question?

Comment: It was just a typo in my question :(

Comment: Can you show the other dependencies you have as well? I would like to test with the same setup as you have and see if I have the same problem too.

Comment: @maba I've added the complete pom.xml

Answer (score 47, accepted):

On my end if I build your project using the `pom.xml` you've showed us, with `apache-poi` declared after `jfreechart`, then as you've mentioned I get a corrupt JAR. Swapping the order of these two dependencies indeed gives me a correct JAR.

I've some previous experience with the `maven-shade-plugin` and when I used it I had trouble with the created JAR's `META-INF` directory, so I've checked that for defects.

I've tried to copy (using Total Commander) the `META-INF` directory somewhere on my local filesystem and what I've noticed is that there were errors while copying the files in `META-INF/licences/`. If I've tried to copy those somewhere individually and it worked but I couldn't copy the whole thing. My conclusion was that the JAR/ZIP archive is corrupt.

What I did was I *entered* that JAR in Total Commander (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDown</kbd> *over* the JAR file) and I *renamed* `thirdpartylicenses.txt` to `thirdpartylicenses.txt.wtf`. Doing this Total Commander offers to save this and it repackages the JAR (I've the Total7zip Total Commander packer plugin installed - if anyone tries this and it doesn't work try it with this installed).

After this. It works.

(I've also tried to repack the whole thing without renaming anything using Cygwin's `unzip`/`zip` commands, but that didn't work the new archive was still corrupt. Total Commander or the plugin I've mentioned does some magic.)

I guess the `maven-shade-plugin` merely creates a corrupt or invalid ZIP/JAR archive. I'm not sure why and maybe what I've described won't work for anyone else but I thought I'd mention it so maybe I could help.

---

I couldn't just leave this alone, so I've dug deeper and I think I've found the answer.

The *bad* JAR contains 65608 entries.
The *good* JAR contains 65450 entries.

Guess what's the upper limit of [the number of entries for a *plain* ZIP file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29#ZIP64)? Yeah. The Wiki article speaks about a ZIP64 format which overcomes this limitation.

The *good* JAR has less entries because the actual dependencies change because of the position of the dependency declarations in your `pom.xml`. ([As described by this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13088093/433835))

I've counted the entries like this.

```
Collections.list(new JarFile("...").entries()).size();
```

I was using [Java 7 which seems to support the new ZIP64 format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9616474/433835), so maybe if someone tries to count the entries in the *bad* JAR using Java 5 or 6 will receive an error (I'm not sure though).

I also tried to run the JAR *exploded*. I've unpacked the whole JAR into a directory and run the whole thing like this.

```
java -cp <dir/ com.mycompany.test.Start
```

Worked like a charm.

---

Bottom line. Don't *overuse* the `maven-shade-plugin`.

I have a project at work where I build my project like this.

- I copy my project's dependencies using the [`maven-dependency-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/). Checkout the [`copy-dependencies` goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html). This copies your dependencies into `target/dependency` if I remember correctly.
- Using the [`maven-jar-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/) I add these dependencies to my final JAR's `MANIFEST.MF` as `Class-Path` entries using these options in the plugins configuration.

  ```
  <classpathPrefix>dependency/</classpathPrefix>
  <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
  ```

  So I'll have `Class-Path` entries like `dependency/<artifactId>-<version>.jar`, etc.
- After this I'm using the [`maven-assembly-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin7) to create a distribution ZIP which contains my final JAR and the whole `dependency/` folder.
- When I deploy my application I can run it like `java -jar final.jar`.

Primarily I've opted to use this solution, because in my project I use some Bouncy Castle JARs which JARs have some extravagant *this and that* inside their `META-INF` directory. When I used the `maven-shade-plugin` to create my final runnable JAR all hell broke loose and I got nasty *that method couldn't be found and this signature is not quite right* errors.

You should be doing something like this also. This Maven shade business is too *shady* to be useful (pun intended).

---

Here's [a blog post on the whole process that I've tried to describe](http://ath3nd.wordpress.com/2013/12/25/packaging-a-multimodule-maven-spring-app-in-a-standalone-jar/) just above (thanks to 
[baba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487649/baba)), maybe it'll help someone in the future.

Comment: That's a really good job you've done there! I agree that this is the problem. +1;

Comment: A work-around: In java 7, it works with 'java -cp final.jar MainClass' but not 'java -jar final.jar' when the number of entries is over 2^16.

Comment: Hey, @Kohányi Róbert, I also had the same conclusion as you, that complex multimodule projects that have weird META-INF or weird resources folder are very hard to be built through shade plugin. That is why i followed your advice and used the 3 simple plugins to build the jar. I wrote a blog post about it: http://ath3nd.wordpress.com/2013/12/25/packaging-a-multimodule-maven-spring-app-in-a-standalone-jar/ Maybe you can update your answer with the full configuration of each plugin so it helps other people who stumble across that question?

Comment: maven-assembly-plugin all the way! This is my personal favorite packaging plugin! +1 answer, had no idea about the limitations of zip in regards to the number of entries!

Answer (score 11):

I ran `mvn dependency:tree` with your setup and it will give a difference when you move the `org.apache.poi` higher up in the dependency declarations.

This is taken from the [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) regarding dependency order:

> *Dependency mediation* - this determines what version of a dependency will be used when multiple versions of an artifact are encountered. Currently, Maven 2.0 only supports using the "nearest definition" which means that it will use the version of the closest dependency to your project in the tree of dependencies. You can always guarantee a version by declaring it explicitly in your project's POM. Note that if two dependency versions are at the same depth in the dependency tree, until Maven 2.0.8 it was not defined which one would win, **but since Maven 2.0.9 it's the order in the declaration that counts: the first declaration wins**.

There seems to be a conflict in your dependency resolution and that is causing your corrupt jar file (don't know why it gets corrupt).

Anyway, here are the diffs between the two poms (left is origin, right is with `org.apache.poi` higher up):

[image]
[image]

(*Maybe it is hard to see at the pictures but if you zoom in you will see.*)

The big difference is that in the non-working pom the `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.2.1` has a dependency on `commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6`, and in the working pom that dependency has been overriden with `commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.5`.

I guess that there is a problem with the `1.6` version of `commons-codec` together with `org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.8` which needs the `1.5` version.

---

**Edit**

After [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13133719/1350762) that explains why the jar file is corrupt (too many entries in the jar) I just want to add a simple solution that at least works for your particular problem.

Add the tag `<minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>` to your `maven-shade-plugin` configuration.

After that your `java -jar target/com.mycompany.test-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` command line will work.

Comment: Thanks for you post. As you mentioned it would be nice if someone is able to figure out why the jar goes corrupt :(. If i remember right, it was also possible to remove all Spring dependencies to let it run. But im currently not on my pc to test it :(